# Are the file ledger of different peers exactly the same(including the block metadata) in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

1. If one of the peers crashed and out of sync, can I just simply copy the block file from another node?
2. Does the block hash include the block metadata?
3. What's the difference between orderer ledger and peerLedger(besides the flag for each transaction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Each peer have it own cert, so copying from other peers will not work.
2. The four metadata stored in a block are SIGNATURES, LAST_CONFIG, TRANSACTIONS_FILTER, ORDERER.
3. Ledger is kept at all peers and, optionally, at a subset of orderers.Peer Ledger differs from the Orderer Ledger in that peers locally maintain a bitmask that tells apart valid transactions from invalid ones.

Comment: AFAIK, SIGNATURES, LAST_CONFIG, ORDERER are added by the orderer, so each OrdererLedger is different from the other nodes in that SIGNATURES are not the same. Maybe blocks of the same height in different peerLedger also came from different orderers?

Comment: It will depend on the configuration, you are running multiple orderer per channel or running a single orderer per channel. If all peers belong to same channel, all will have the same copy of ledger with proper permissions. If peers belong to different channels than they can have different block height based on the CA/MSP configuration.

Comment: 1. How peer cert might affect the content of the peers ledger? 2. While the content of the metadata includes signatures, last config block sequence number and transactions filter it's not part of the block hash, simply because metadata being updated during validation phase, prior to commit.

Comment: Peer cert has nothing to do with the peer leger, but orderer cert does. Considering that peers of different organization may pull blocks from different orderers,  peer ledger would be different. Am I wrong?@Artem Barger

Comment: Peer cert are used to verify the peer, if peer cert do not match in crytpo-config  it will not be able to endorse or commit to the ledger.